# How to setup a deployable SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, putty, tunnel

I would like to find a quick and easy way to deploy an SSH tunnel to people who are either not very tech savvy, or just for people I don't want to sit there and explain the details. I am trying to figure out for example a custom compiled .exe for windows that basically combines putty, pageant, and the tunnel config in a simple one click solution. ie they run the .exe which is already preconfigured to request their SSH key password and then creates the tunnel for them. Can anyone suggest the best way to go about this?

Comment: why not do a bat file that runs those commands with the apropriate switches,

Comment: That would require packaging the additional utilities. Now if I could take putty and pageant and recompile them into a single .exe along with the batch instructions then ok.

Comment: Then you can use self-extracting archive: https://superuser.com/q/42788/213663