# How can I pack multiple bash scripts into one single executable

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, packages

I have multiple bash scripts and resources required by these scripts (like music files and images) and I want to pack them all into one executable file.

For example:

```
$ find Scripts/

Scripts/
Scripts/main.sh
Scripts/bin/1.sh
Scripts/bin/2.sh
Scripts/src/music.mp3
```

Now, I want to pack all these into one executable which if I execute, executes the `Scripts/main.sh` file.

How can I do that?

Comment: How does one script (e.g. `main.sh`) call or source another? If by its absolute path then there's a problem; If by its relative path then there's another problem. If by `$PATH` then another. One solution I can think of is refactoring code, so dependent files just define shell functions, `main.sh` sources them all and uses the functions. Then it's relatively easy to replace `. …`/`source …` with actual content (definitions) to get one big standalone `main.sh`.

Comment: Does [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/42788/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-file-after-extraction-from-a-7-zip-self-extracting-a) using 7Zip solve your problem?

Comment: What is the motivation here? It is for distributing the "package" in one file that the user just has to execute? Other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use the **Shell Archive (shar)** utility. It is maybe not installed by default, but likely present in the repository of your distribution.

Very much like `tar` it can create an single-file archive of a list of files. The difference is that the archive file is self-extracting: this is a shell script that has to be run.

In your case :

`shar -M -D -Q Scripts/ > myarchive.sh` packs the whole Scripts/ folder into `myarchive.sh`.

Then you can pass `myarchive.sh` to someone else. By running `sh myarchive.sh` he will locally unpack Scripts/ and all its content.

But this is not enough, as you also want to execute Scripts/main.sh . You have then to add this command at the end of `myarchive.sh`, and the full command is:

`shar -M -D -Q Scripts/ | head -n -1 > myarchive.sh && echo "Scripts/main.sh" >> myarchive.sh`

The purpose of `head -n -1` is to remove the last line of the archiv, which is `exit 0`, otherwise the command you are adding won't be executed. I haven't tested since this syntax doesn't work on macOS (I used `grep -v "exit 0"`instead, but there can be edge effects with that).

Now Scripts/main.sh will be executed once the archive is unpacked.

I couldn't solve a (small) problem: the `-Q` option is supposed to make the unpack stage quiet, without output messages. But there are still some of them, I don't why...

Comment: `sed '$d'` should remove the last line on any kind of Unix